# Eclipse - C++ - debugger terminating immediately

Tags: c++, debugging, eclipse-cdt

When I debugged a C program, with breakpoints - it was all fine.
Now I`m debugging a C++ program (simple cout print one), and it just "terminates" immediately - instead of going through some of the breakpoints I put. On debug mode it doesn't even print the cout (that IS printed on a regular run).
I don't really know what's going wrong - debugger options? Compiler?

EDIT: So several comments said I need a code attached and more information. So here is the code and info! (Tell me if its enough.)

**Steps taken:** literally created by eclipse "new project -> c++ project -> 'HelloWorld C++ project' / MinGW GCC" with 'debug/release' ticks marked and then compiled and debugged (nothing else!).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

As I said, works in run mode but debugger doesn't work.
Tell me if any more information is needed. I'm very new, and cynical comments like "your project has no code so that why it failed" don't help me TBH.

Comment: No code? What debugger? What steps? Close.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Did you compile in Debug or Release mode? The latter might be a reason why you cannot debug the executable.

Comment: Are you sure your debugger's attached to the process you've booted? (I'm not familiar with eclipse but it seems a likely cause, if the program runs as expected and the breakpoints have no special highlighting)

Comment: judging by the program you attached to this question, it looks like your c++ project is empty. Please create a c++ project before trying to debug it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I dont think so, just opened it and recompiled in regular mode. same result @It's coming home can you explain more? I`m not THAT advance as to check if the debugger is "attached" (but notice it does work on C!)

Comment: @Itai Try to load your executable compiled in debug mode to the MinGW gdb from a command line, if that works, your problem is probably somewhere in your projects debugger settings (would be nice if you add these to your question also, it's unlikely that the code you're showing has a problem itself).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UPDATE: I didn't solve the problem in eclipse, so I downloaded Visual-Studio 2017 ("Express"/"Community" its called) and it works there. 
In the beginning it also didn't because it didn't find some DLLs, but allowing an option called "Microsoft Symbol Server" in its' debugger settings solved it and now it **works**.

So problem "bypassed" rather than "solved" I would say (So if anyone experiences the same problems as mine, doing what I did will allow you to work on c++).

Comment: That's not even close being a "bypass" or workaround. You're using a completely different toolchain. Not a useful answer for anyone researching on a similar problem.

Answer (score 4):

For those still looking for guidance on this: I had the same issue and had no idea what was wrong. Pretty much doing the same procedure as OP here, using the hello world project.

I can't rule out coincidence, but what I ended up doing is setting up a PATH Environment variable to point to my MinGW installation, and now I can step through my code in debug.

*Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment: add variable named “PATH” with directory of “[location of MingW]\bin”* 
Ex. C:\MinGW\bin

You would probably need to point it to whatever compiler/debugger you have installed. Hope that helps.